# Want to record multi track at home pc

Tags: sound-effects-recording, home-studio

How i can record multi track using my home pc??

i want to record each track individually so i can edit effects on each track as neccessity.

which hardware or/and software require to complete this job?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://sound.stackexchange.com/q/26797/6957.  I realize the other question is about electronic music, but the answers are not.  Short answer here... read!  Your question is way to broad.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer already stated, you will need both an audio interface, and a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation), but I'll expand on this a little to get you started in the right direction so you can make an informed decision when acquiring these tools.

**The Interface**

To put it simply, an interface is a box that takes analog signals, and converts them into digital signals that can be interpreted by the computer (and vice versa). In many cases, this box acts as the main hub for all audio coming in and coming out of your computer.

Interfaces come in many different configurations (and price points) based on the user's needs. A basic configuration might have:

- Preamps with XLR and/or 1/4" inputs (ex: for microphones, guitars, etc)
- 1/4" Line level inputs (ex: keyboards)
- Headphone preamp (monitor your computer audio and/or your live instrument through headphones)
- Line level Audio output jacks (for external speakers)
- A way to connect the interface to the computer (USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt, etc)

Interfaces with multiple inputs will generally let you record all inputs at the same time, and will be saved as separate tracks inside your DAW.

Since interfaces can range from about $100 to several thousand dollars, I would suggest figuring out what your needs are (how many instruments do you need to record at one time? is portability a factor? How do you plan to connect it to your computer? etc) and then visit your local music store.

Presonus, M-Audio, and Focusrite are a few brands I've really enjoyed, and all have great options at several price points. Not trying to push you in any sort of direction, but it may be a good place to start with your research.

**The DAW**

The DAW is software that allows you to save, edit, arrange, and playback your audio files. I won't go into depth on the definition, but you will definitely be needing one for multi-track recording.

Many companies are putting out free "lite" versions of their software, which works great for general purposes, and is a really great opportunity to try out the software before buying a more professional version.

A few free options I would recommend for PC are:

- ProTools First (most pro studios use pro tools)
- Presonus Studio One Free
- Audacity (Open source software)

Again, the choice of DAW depends on your needs, but a free version will probably be enough to get you started, and allow you to make an informed decision if/when you need to upgrade

Comment: Thanx. Openly i am novice to all this but i want to make home studio for own purpose. I have 6 input stereo echo mixer and one mono amplifier with 5 inputs. I used line in to record one track with good quality for all (5 to 6 mic) but i can't improve things if somewhere mistakes. Suggest a book how i can start with this. also please,suggest DAW models for min. 7 channels.

Comment: I would highly recommend the book "Guerrilla Home Recording: How to Get Great Sound From Any Studio (No Matter How Weird or Cheap Your Gear Is)"
Here's a link: http://www.amazon.com/Guerrilla-Home-Recording-Studio-Matter-ebook/dp/B001T4YU3O

Comment: All DAWs should be able to support your needs. A good 8 channel interface may be expensive for a beginner (approx. $600 new). I would suggest looking for a used Presonus firepod, or firestudio. You can probably find them for around $200 - $300.

Comment: Can i use sound cards to make basic set for beginning?? i damm sure to make,this studio but as a novice it costs,more.

Comment: So as i learn sound editing, i make purchase for good quality daw. but there is no meaning of all this without masteting sound editing.

Comment: Do u know any interface for such purpose?? I can produce 6 audio signals individually by some means but how to put5 it on pc as pc,contain only 2 mic input and 1 line in. basically i want some hardware to put 8 live audio to pc. can i use rs 232 or usb ports?? i have sound mixer but it will give single streo output. i will manage software using trials to check every thing ok or not. after i will purchase. tell me about audio interface

Comment: Here is an example of an interface. http://www.presonus.com/products/AudioBox-1818VSL
You can plug 8 instruments into the front, and there is a USB output in the back which you connect to your PC. This will allow you to record all 8 instruments on separate tracks

Comment: Was this helpful? Would you consider accepting/up-voting this answer?

Comment: Yup johanne  it is useful for me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a very bad sounding finished product, on top of these (two) answers, you will need something to output the sound for more accurate monitoring. Something a lot better than PC speakers. Either half-decent headphones, active monitors or passive monitors and an amp.

If you are truly starting with no knowledge on the subject, I would recommend buying a book before anything else!

Comment: suggest headphone for doing this job.